# (Forbidden 403) The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared

Tags: php, html, ubuntu, nginx, http-status-code-403

I'm starting to build a small website and everything was doing great until I try to run it on a server.  At first, I was texting on localhost with xampp and everything was going smoothly, but when I tried it on a server, when I enter the URL, I get the following error on Firefox

> **403 Forbidden nginx/1.10.3 (Ubuntu)**
>   The character encoding of the HTML document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the page must be declared in the document or in the transfer protocol.

and the following on Microsoft Edge

> HTTP403: FORBIDDEN - The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfil it.

I tried to add  but couldn't get it to work. So I figured I'd to a small index.php file in another directory on the server to test and I get the same thing.  Here's the code of this test file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Hello World!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

Since it doesn't even work with this exemple, my guess is that it has nothing to do with the character encoding.  The file has all permissions and I've tried changing the ownership of it and nothing happens.

I'm kind of at a lost now, anyone knows what could be the issue?

Thank you

**EDIT :**
The server error log is

> 2018/02/08 20:21:00 [error] 1290#1290: *20598506 directory index of "/var/www/html/public_html/civilia/openTripPlanner-web/" is forbidden, client: 96.20.96.104, server: _, request: "GET /civilia/openTripPlanner-web/ HTTP/1.1", host: "67.212.79.244"

**Edit 2 :**
Here's what the configuration file (/etc/nginx/sites-avalaible/default) looks like

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/public_html;

    # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html index.php;

    server_name _;
    autoindex on;
    location / {
            autoindex on;
            # First attempt to serve request as file, then
            # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
            try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
```

**Edit 3 :** 
The problem was that when I added the `index.php` to the config file, I forgot to reload the server (dumb me).  So now I did and everything is running fine

Comment: Yeah, that message about the character encoding sounds to me like it might have been added by the browser rather than nginx ... What does the server error log say?

Comment: '2018/02/08 20:21:00 [error] 1290#1290: *20598506 directory index of "/var/www/html/public_html/civilia/openTripPlanner-web/" is forbidden, client: 96.20.96.104, server: _, request: "GET /civilia/openTripPlanner-web/ HTTP/1.1", host: "67.212.79.244"'

Comment: Might simply need to enable directory listing then ...? http://nginxlibrary.com/enable-directory-listing/

Comment: Or maybe rather define the `index` file(s) to be scanned for, since you said you put an index.php in there, so that doesn't seem to be set as default on your server?

Comment: There was indeed no mention of `index.php` in /etc/nginx/sites-available/default, so I add it as well as `autoindex on`., but I still get the error